# Why is this a baseless merge in tfs?

Tags: tfs

I have branch X. Off it branches branch Y and off Y branches Z.

Now I merge from Z to X and TFS complains that it is a baseless merge.

Why?

**EDIT 1**

To be more concrete, here are the branches:

1. X - `$/xyz`
2. Y - `$/rtqa/1/xyz`
3. Z - `$/preprod/1/xyz`

So, `$/rtqa/1/xyz` branches off `$/xyz` and at some point `$/preprod/1/xyz` branches off `$/rtqa/1/xyz`:

```
$/xyz
|
+-----$/rtqa/1/xyz
      |
      +-----$/preprod/1/xyz
```

The merge is from `$/preprod/1/xyz` to `$/xyz` of a single changeset.

TFS insists it is a baseless merge. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because TFS VC maintains relationship only between parent and child, not with grand-parent and child.

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d86000e9-2430-4a25-bf55-f53fd701fe15/merge-to-grandparent-version-can-only-merge-to-immediate-parentchild-?forum=tfsversioncontrol) is the similar forum for reference.